# DbContext not compiling?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, compiler-errors

i am following a step by step to learn mvc and creating a music shop but for some reason i cant get the following code to work..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class MusicStoreEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The DBcontext, DbSet and DbSet are giving errors...

> Error  1   The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must add a reference to the `EntityFramework.dll` assembly to your project. The simplest way to do this is installing the corresponding [NuGet package](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/EntityFramework). If you have installed the [ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208140) this NuGet package is referenced by default when you create a new project. If not, simply install it.